# Wordpress - Compartilhe das rede sociais puxa foto errada

Tags: wordpress, imagem, facebook, blog

Quando alguém vai compartilhar uma notícia no meu site (wordpress), ele puxa a imagem errada, vocês sabem o por quê, ou como consertar?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instale um plugin do [Wordpress SEO](https://wordpress.org/plugins/wordpress-seo/). Ele irá te ajudar a resolver esse problema.Basta configurar a *Set Featured Image* em cada post.

Comment: Boa, deu certo, obrigado!